Best POM for Google Spanner and Dataflow
I've been getting bizarre ClassNotFound errors in this io.grpc library, strange timeout errors, etc. Plus I saw on an old document there's a need to enforce the minimum version. I've tried building a pom.xml file by running it and adding a library whenever the Google artifact doesn't bring in enough but requires something else. It's becoming unwieldy and brittle. This is my current POM. Please suggest a minimal way, such as using that  of some Google BOM. I assume I need the latest GCP version. I'm using Java 17.
Key things I need are, GCP Spanner tables, and GCP dataflow:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spanner-table-copy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spanner Table Copy</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <beam.version>2.48.0</beam.version>
        <google.cloud.version>6.81.0</google.cloud.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.36</lombok.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.9.3</junit.jupiter.version>
        <mockito.version>5.3.1</mockito.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.32</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Lombok for boilerplate reduction -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google Cloud Spanner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner</artifactId>
            <version>${google.cloud.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Beam dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J for logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dnet.bytebuddy.experimental=true</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.SpannerTableCopyApp</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



Hope it doesn't come up as blunt/naive, but have you tried using the libraries bom in your <dependencyManagement/> to let it figure out the right grpc/protobuf dependencies? That's the usual way it's proposed in these libraries.
